# Swift type-erasure for protocol with Self type requirement

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, type-erasure

I am trying to design a simple game engine for fun and educational purposes. I have a `Game` protocol that represents my game and `Entity` protocol that represents an entity (like the player or opponent). Finally, I have an `EntityComponent` protocol which implementations update an `Entity`. It looks like this in Swift:

```swift
protocol Game {
    var entities: [Entity] { get }
}

protocol Entity {
    var components: [EntityComponent] { get }
}

protocol EntityComponent {
    func update(_ entity: Entity, deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval)
}
```

I want my entity components to be generalized using entity they update. In Swift, I can use `associatedtype`:

```swift
protocol EntityComponent {
    associatedtype EntityType: Entity
    func update(_ entity: EntityType, deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval)
}
```

However, this would produce a compilation error for `Entity` protocol:

```swift
protocol Entity {
    var components: [EntityComponent] { get } // ERROR!
}
```

> Protocol 'EntityComponent' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

This issue could be solved by defining type-erasure for `EntityComponent` protocol, and updating `Entity` like this:

```swift
protocol Entity {
    var components: [AnyEntityComponent<Self>] { get }
}

final class AnyEntityComponent<EntityType: Entity>: EntityComponent {
    init<T: EntityComponent>(_ component: T) where T.EntityType == EntityType {
        self.update = component.update
    }

    func update(_ entity: EntityType, deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        update(entity, seconds)
    }

    private let update: (EntityType, TimeInterval) -> Void
}
```

Unfortunately, that change in the `Entity` protocol produces another issue. This time in `Game` protocol:

```swift
protocol Game {
    var entities: [Entity] { get } // ERROR!
}
```

> Protocol 'Entity' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I am not sure how to fix this one, as I can't do it by defining type-erasure (as in case of `EntityComponent`).

I will appreciate any hints and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It may help to remove the associated type requirement and use generics instead:

```
protocol EntityComponent {
    func update<T: Entity>(_ entity: T, deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval)
}
```

Comment: That's a good hint, thanks! However, I would like a single `EntityComponent` implementation to update single `Entity` implementation, for example `class PlayerEntity` and `class PlayerEntityComponent`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I had the same kind of requirement recently and could not figure out an elegant way to do it.

Comment: Check out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/74/understanding-protocol-associated-types-and-their-constraints. It didn't work for me because I was using structs not classes, but I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check it out